# Generator that computes average value of an iterator

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I have an iterator that evaluates prime numbers. I want to create a generator with prime-iterator as input parameter that evaluates average value of looped prime numbers:

```
from itertools import islice, tee

def only_primes(stream):
    try:
        while True:
            is_valid, value = next(stream)
            while not is_valid:
                is_valid, value = next(stream)
            yield value
    except StopIteration:
        return

def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False, n
    elif n == 2:
        return True, n
    sqrt_n = int(n**0.5)+1
    return len([i for i in range(2, sqrt_n+1) if n % i == 0]) == 0, n

prime_iterator = only_primes(map(is_prime, range(100)))

def prime_av(stream):
"""Generator that yields average value of looped prime numbers"""
    n = 0
    stats = dict()
    stats['mean'] = 0
    try:
        while True:
            prime = next(stream)
            n += 1
            stats['mean'] *= n - 1
            stats['mean'] += prime
            stats['mean'] /= n
            yield stats
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

If I loop over both `raw` and `prime_av(stats)` iterators simultaneously, only the last average value is printed. Why?

```
raw, stats = tee(prime_iterator)    
list(islice(zip(raw, prime_av(stats)), 10))
```

output:

```
[(2, {'mean': 12.9}),
 (3, {'mean': 12.9}),
 (5, {'mean': 12.9}),
 (7, {'mean': 12.9}),
 (11, {'mean': 12.9}),
 (13, {'mean': 12.9}),
 (17, {'mean': 12.9}),
 (19, {'mean': 12.9}),
 (23, {'mean': 12.9}),
 (29, {'mean': 12.9})]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the averaging iterator is keeping changing the same dictionary object and yielding it.
If you print the result during the loop the result is what you would have expected, but if you put the result in a list (like you are doing) then in the end the list will contain just references to the same object that of course will also have as value the last computed average.

Changing the code for example to:

```
def prime_av(stream):
    """Generator that yields average value of looped prime numbers"""
    n = 0
    S = 0
    try:
        while True:
            prime = next(stream)
            n += 1
            S *= n - 1
            S += prime
            S /= n
            yield {"mean": S}
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

will behave as you expect because at each iteration a new fresh dictionary will be allocated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
stats['mean'] = 0
```

and here:

```
yield stats
```

You see the same value printed repeatedly because you're generating references to the same dictionary repeatedly. These references are all saved in a list. You then print the list. If you want to see this dictionary's intermediate states each time it's updated, print it each time it changes rather than doing all the updates and printing them. This is as simple as changing this:

```
print(list(islice(zip(raw, prime_av(stats)), 10)))
```

to something like this:

```
for i in islice(zip(raw, prime_av(stats)), 10):
    print(*i)
```

If you want a list of these means, you'll need to add them to a list instead of repeatedly updating a single value, by changing this:

```
def prime_av(stream):
    """Generator that yields average value of looped prime numbers"""
    n = 0
    stats = dict()
    stats['mean'] = 0
    try:
        while True:
            prime = next(stream)
            n += 1
            stats['mean'] *= n - 1
            stats['mean'] += prime
            stats['mean'] /= n
            yield stats
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

to this:

```
def prime_av(stream):
    """Generator that yields average value of looped prime numbers"""
    n = 0
    stats = dict()
    stats['mean'] = [0]
    try:
        while True:
            prime = next(stream)
            n += 1
            stats['mean'].append(stats['mean'][-1])
            stats['mean'][-1] *= n - 1
            stats['mean'][-1] += prime
            stats['mean'][-1] /= n
            yield stats
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

Then, when you do this:

```
x = list(islice(zip(raw, prime_av(stats)), 10))
```

The dictionary of values is in `x[1][1]`:

```
{'mean': [0, 2.0, 2.5, 3.3333333333333335, 4.25, 5.6, 6.833333333333333, 8.285714285714286, 9.625, 11.11111111111111, 12.9]}
```